# Enter the loop once in C

Tags: c++, arduino

I have small program that running .The code has been attached below.I wanted to run program which can invoke multiple functions depending on state of key being pressed. Problem I am facing once I enter my `void function()`, after while directly come **printing welcome to main**. I wanted to keep running hello when entered loop if up arrow pressed keep printing **welcome** unless ***button == right***

This is my `main` program

```
main()
{
    while(button!=NONE)
    {
        function();printf("welcome to mAIN");
    }
}
```

Here I am checking my test cases

```
void function()
{
    int option=1;
    while(option<3)
    {
        case 1:
            while(button!=right)
            {
                counter=1;
                switch(counter)
                {
                    case 1: printf("hello");break;
                    case 2:printf("welcome");break;
                    case 3:printf("enclosure");break;
                }

                if(button==up)
                    counter=counter+1;
                if(button==down)
                    counter=counter-1;
            }


        case 2:
            while(button!=right)
            {
                set_counter=1;
                switch(set_counter)
                {
                    case 1: printf("hello");break;
                    case 2:printf("welcome");break;
                    case 3:printf("enclosure");break;
                }

                if(button==up)
                    set_counter=set_counter+1;
                if(button==down)
                    set_counter=set_counter-1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code would be much easier to understand if it was indented properly.

Comment: is there any way keep proper indenting ,

Comment: Your outer `case` has no `switch`!

Comment: i already check this condition doe-snot worked

Comment: @user3378973 its not too clear with the kind of English you are using,what you really wanna achieve .try writing small sentences,please. be clear

Comment: you have to use do while statement

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   main()
    {
    do
     {
      function();
      printf("welcome to mAIN");
     }
     while(button!=NONE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use do while statement execute atleast one time

```
main()
{
do
 {
  function();printf("welcome to mAIN");
 }
 while(button!=NONE);
}
```